# VSTO Unit Testing Office AddIn in C# .NET via RequestComAddInAutomationService

Tags: c#, testing, com, vsto, office-interop

I have worked and read through various StackOverflow questions and other tutorials and documentation over the past weeks (N.B. some of them below) to try and find a way of unit testing a VSTO AddIn.

Unfortunately, it always results in an `E_NOINTERFACE` exception in my tests.

The code I am using is below - one extract of the ThisAddin partial class overriding the `RequestComAddinAutomationService`, another describing the test utility interface, the test itself, as well as an additional assembly extract proving that the AddIn assembly and its internals are visible to the test.

> **My question is**: why is this not working?  I am pretty sure that this follows the generally accepted practices of VSTO testing.

If the below is not possible anymore, how should one go about testing VSTO?  Is .NET remoting/IPC the only solution?

#### ThisAddin.cs

```
public partial class ThisAddin 
{
    #region Testing Utilities

    private AddinHelper _comAddinObject;

    protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
    {
        // This is being called when I debug/run my project, but not when I run the tests
        return _comAddinObject ?? (_comAddinObject = new AddinHelper());
    }

    #endregion
}

#region Testing Utilities

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IAddinHelper
{
    Presentation GetPresentation();
    string GetString();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IAddinHelper))]
public class AddinHelper : StandardOleMarshalObject, IAddinHelper
{
    public Presentation GetPresentation()
    {
        return Globals.ThisAddin... [...];
    }

    public string GetString()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

#endregion
```

#### AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Tests")]
```

#### MyUnitTest.cs (has a reference to `MyProject`)

```
[TestClass]
public class BasicTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInstantiates()
    {
        var application = new Application();
        var doc = application.Presentations.Open(@"C:\Presentation.pptx",
            MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        var comAddins = application.COMAddIns;
        var comAddin = comAddins.Item("MyProject"); // Returns okay
        var comObject = (IAddinHelper) comAddin.Object; // Exception occurs

        Assert.AreEqual(true, true); // Never reached

        doc.Close();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the project's settings are set to "Register for COM interop" and Visual Studio runs elevated without errors - running it as non-admin results in the DLLs not being registered; therefore, I also know that the COM objects **are** registered.

#### Resulting Exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in MyProject.Tests.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'MyProject.IAddinHelper'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{59977378-CC79-3B27-9093-82CD7A05CF74}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

StackOverflow

- [How to call VSTO class from other c# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553446/how-to-call-vsto-class-from-other-c-sharp-project)
- [Unit Testing VSTO projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906070/unit-testing-vsto-projects)
- [VSTO Add-ins, COMAddIns and RequestComAddInAutomationService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875278/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice) (`Register for COM Interop` doesn't change anything)
- [Why cannot I cast my COM object to the interface it implements in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938467/why-cannot-i-cast-my-com-object-to-the-interface-it-implements-in-c/16943296#16943296) (the issue is likely not STAThread related)
- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/how-do-i-unit-test-word-addin-written-in-c

Microsoft

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varsha/2010/08/17/writing-automated-test-cases-for-vsto-application/  <-- Even with this supposedly working sample project, I am getting the exact same error.
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx
- General workflow background: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386298.aspx

I honestly don't know how one is supposed to test VSTO Add-Ins without this working.

Comment: This answer may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943296/2592875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943296/2592875)

Comment: Thanks for the link - I did actually come across it before, and the STAThread attribute did not, unfortunately, yield any results. Thanks for chipping in, though!

Comment: I was able to get my VSTO Outlook AddIn project working with xUnit in Visual Studio 2019 *without* the need to use RequestComAddinAutomationService, COM attributes or setting "Register for COM interop".  See my question/answer on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75739113/20036274).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

The Project with methods to be Tested has to use the PIA Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint via the **.Net reference** tab.

In the Unit Test Project you have to use the Microsoft Powerpoint 1X.0 Object Library via the **COM reference** tab - its an ActiveX.

[image]

The confusing thing is in Solution Explorer they are both called: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint

---

When you specify the correct References you'll see this error on the line where the exception occurs:

> Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

To solve that simply add a .Net reference to the Microsoft.CSharp.dll in the Unit Test project.

---

Next we will run into the error you're seeing.

Firstly add a unique GUID to the Interface *& class* (this will overcome the error):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("B523844E-1A41-4118-A0F0-FDFA7BCD77C9")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IAddinHelper
{
    string GetPresentation();
    string GetString();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("A523844E-1A41-4118-A0F0-FDFA7BCD77C9")]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IAddinHelper))]
public class AddinHelper : StandardOleMarshalObject, IAddinHelper
```

Secondly temporarily make the `private AddinHelper _comAddinObject;` public in Scope *(you can do your [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Tests")] later when its working)*.

Thirdly, check that Powerpoint has not disabled the COM add-in. This sometimes happens silently, without the Office App complaining.

[image]

Lastly, make sure Register for COM is ticked.

Viola:

[image]

---

**Ref:** I pulled my hair out working this out years ago helping this fellow SO'r: [Moq & Interop Types: works in VS2012, fails in VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202120/moq-interop-types-works-in-vs2012-fails-in-vs2010)

Comment: Jeremy, you made my week! Thank you so much - this has worked a charm and my level of happiness right now is beyond words. I too, have been pulling my hair out over this, left it for a while, and then started obsessing about it again. Thanks again!