# Unit testing Excel addin using VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, testing, vsto, office-interop

I've been trying to test my addin without success, and even after looking at various sources like [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varsha/2010/08/17/writing-automated-test-cases-for-vsto-application/) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121396/vsto-unit-testing-office-addin-in-c-sharp-net-via-requestcomaddinautomationserv)

I can't seem to be able to do it.
Here's my current code (I trimmed to only have the relevant parts)

### AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAddInTest")]
```

### ThisAddIn.cs

```
private AddinHelper _comAddinObject;
protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
{
    return _comAddinObject ?? (_comAddinObject = new AddinHelper());
}
```

### AddinHelper.cs

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("B523844E-1A41-4118-A0F0-FDFA7BCD77C9")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IAddinHelper
{
    string GetString();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("A523844E-1A41-4118-A0F0-FDFA7BCD77C9")]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IAddinHelper))]
public class AddinHelper : StandardOleMarshalObject, IAddinHelper
{
    public string GetString()
    {
        return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name;
    }
}
```

### ThisAddInTest.cs

```
Application = new Application();
Workbook = Application.Workbooks.Add();
COMAddIns comAddins = Application.COMAddIns;
COMAddIn comAddin = comAddins.Item("MyAddIn");
IAddinHelper comObject = (IAddinHelper) comAddin.Object;
```

The main project references the .NET Assembly version of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` with Embed Interop Types set to true.
My test project references my VSTO project, and the COM (ActiveX) version of the Interop.

The exception I get is:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'MyAddIn.IAddinHelper'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B523844E-1A41-4118-A0F0-FDFA7BCD77C9}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I currently use Office 2013 (so Office 15.0) and the references are all pointing to that version, .NET 4.5.3 and Visual Stuio Community 2017. The SO link that I provided seems to be the exact same issue, however I still have the exception when running my tests unlike there.

Comment: I was able to get my VSTO Outlook AddIn project working with xUnit in Visual Studio 2019 *without* the need to use RequestComAddinAutomationService, COM attributes or setting "Register for COM interop".  See my question/answer on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75739113/20036274).