# Checking whether a CheckBox control is checked or unchecked

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

i'm trying to coding vb.net
and i'm in a hard situation
beacuse i don't know why cant running my code
Purpose is Checking CheckBox Control(Form Control in Excel) is Checked Or UnChecked

Here is Code and **error is BC30512 String,Integer convert Error in IF condition**

```
Dim Message As String
Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(my_excel_path)
Dim xlSt = As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWb.Worksheets(sheet_name),Worksheet)

**If (xlSt.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1) Then**
Message = "is Checked"
Else
Message = "is UnChecked"
End If

MsgBox(Message)
```

plz help me

I need a correct grammar
i tried xlSt to ActiveSheet.Shapes() and this isn't work (it worked in vba Excel, so i tried)

and my new Code is

```
Dim excelApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
Dim xlWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
Dim shape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape = Nothing

xlWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

'Get the worksheet
xlWorksheet = CType(xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

Dim checkBoxNames() As String = {"Check Box 1", "Check Box 2", "Check Box 3", "Check Box 4","Check Box 5","Check Box 6","Check Box 7"} 'Add more names here as needed
Dim isChecked As Boolean

For Each checkBoxName In checkBoxNames
    For Each shape In xlWorksheet.Shapes
        If shape.Name = checkBoxName Then
            isChecked = (CInt(shape.ControlFormat.Value) = 1)
            Console.WriteLine(checkBoxName & ": " & isChecked.ToString())
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

xlWorkbook.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

With VB.Net its a bit different to VBA, this is what you're missing:

```
Dim checkboxControl As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.CheckBox
```

Insert your code here.

And use these two lines to detect if the CheckBox is checked:

```
checkboxControl = CType(xlWorksheet.CheckBoxes("CheckBox1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.CheckBox)

If checkboxControl.Value = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTriState.xlOn Then
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!!
I tried your code, but can't find Excel.XlTriState at Ms document
how can i use that??

Comment: You need to reference the PIA's (the Primary Interop Assemblies), and here is the catch you reference the COM ActiveX for Unit Testing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121396/vsto-unit-testing-office-addin-in-c-sharp-net-via-requestcomaddinautomationserv

Comment: Is there a way to do it without PIA? cause, My env is not VSTO

Comment: Sorry, can you say that in another way, it doesn't make sense. The PIA's are needed for the Interop between .Net using a VSTO Project and calls to the native Office DLLs. Your Environment is definitely VSTO, `Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`. At this point I think you're better off getting a book on the topic if you're trying to work-around things like the core requirements its obviously not going to fly and you'll get deterred.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried xlCheckBox but this is not working in my office version, so i change Excel.Shape and it worked

Comment: That means you've tagged your question wrong, you're using VBA, not VB.NET.

Comment: oh.. Thanks 
I update my code 
Is This Code VBA? Not VB.NET??